# I am trying to transform a signal into multiple images but the images are not clear

Tags: matlab

I have a signal that contains three distinct images, this means that I have three frequencies or peaks, and each one corresponds to a picture.

I have a function that converts a signal into an image. 
I'm using the low pass, high pass, and band pass filters in Matlab to filter out the frequencies I want. When I use the LP filter, the image I get is clear. 
But when I use both the HP and BP filter, the images I get are not clear/(contain noise?). 
I'm using the "butter" and "filter" functions. I'm not really sure how to clear up the images or if I'm doing the wrong steps. 
What I'm doing is using the filter, then using a tdft function, then I plot that and use the signal-to-image function I have to get the image. I'd appreciate any help.

Examples:

Signal with all three images:
[image]

TDFT of image:
[image]

First image after lowpass:
[image]

Second image after bandpass:
[image]

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of context and details. It's entirely unclear how your signal and your pictures are related to start with.

Comment: Could you post some examples and explain what is not clear in the images?

Comment: Well, the signal contains the information that is then converted into images. It contains the info for the 3 pictures, meaning I need to isolate each 'peak'. I'm not really sure how to explain that in more detail.  As for the code, I'm mostly going with :

 [b,a] = butter(9,0.3,'low');
Y = filter(b,a,z);
Y_t = tdftfast(Y);
figure
plot(nu,abs(Y_t))
title('LOW')
figure
present_image(Y)  %function I got from my teacher

I use this with low,high and band pass. As to what is not clear in the picture, I guess it's that it's got grey lines going across the image.

Comment: Could you please post the images?  If you can't put them directly into the question, then post them somewhere and put links to them in your question and someone here can edit them into your question

Comment: signal with all three images: http://imgur.com/jhKYMGT , how it looks likes with tdft: http://imgur.com/tMIMimt , first image with low pass filter: http://imgur.com/PQ78Yce , second image when using a bandpass filter : http://imgur.com/vMmOakA .

Comment: Ok, so your signal contains information about the scanlines of three different images, modulated to different frequency bands. What modulation method has been used for that?

Comment: Could you post your code, or at least the relevant sections of it?  It looks to me like you may be using the wrong parameters for the filters.

Comment: I'm not sure which modulation method is used.  About the code, then it's pretty short : [u,i] = butter(9, [0.3 0.7], 'bandpass'); ---
[c,v] = butter(9,0.3, 'low'); ---
[p,l] = butter(9,0.7, 'high'); ---  bla = filter(b,a,z); ---
blo = tdftfast(bla); ---
bli = ifft(blo); --- Think that's all the relevent parts, the rest is just plotting different variables or using the function i have to turn a signal into an image

Comment: Right now I get a result after using a low pass filter, and a high pass filter. So i get two of the images. But the third option, which is the bandpass, is not working. I don't get a clear image at all.